# How can I get the length of a video file from the console?

Tags: linux, video, vlc-media-player, ffmpeg, mplayer

Suppose we have a video file some_video.

How can I get its length from a shell script (with mplayer/transcode/gstreamer/vlc/ffmpeg/whatever)?

```
VIDEO_LENGTH_IN_SECONDS=`ffmpeg .... -i some_video ... | grep -o .....`
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
ffprobe -i some_video -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

will return the video duration in seconds.

Comment: sorry for the dump question, but how to get it in minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 31):

Something similar to:

```
ffmpeg -i input 2>&1 | grep "Duration"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//
```

This will deliver: `HH:MM:SS.ms`. You can also use `ffprobe`, which is supplied with most FFmpeg installations:

```
ffprobe -show_format input | sed -n '/duration/s/.*=//p'
```

… or:

```
ffprobe -show_format input | grep duration | sed 's/.*=//')
```

To convert into seconds (and retain the milliseconds), pipe into:

```
awk '{ split($1, A, ":"); print 3600*A[1] + 60*A[2] + A[3] }'
```

---

To convert it into milliseconds, pipe into:

```
awk '{ split($1, A, ":"); print 3600000*A[1] + 60000*A[2] + 1000*A[3] }'
```

If you want just the seconds without the milliseconds, pipe into:

```
awk '{ split($1, A, ":"); split(A[3], B, "."); print 3600*A[1] + 60*A[2] + B[1] }'
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Also tcprobe is desiged for it, but it doesn't work well on my system.

Comment: ...my edit was rejected, so I'll post here that the first step can be more concisely accomplished with `ffprobe`, a tool designed for exactly these sort of purposes that is packaged with `ffmpeg`: `ffprobe -show_format input | sed -n '/duration/s/.*=//p'` (or `ffprobe -show_format input | grep duration | sed 's/.*=//'`). Maybe @slhck can edit this straight into the answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 movie.mp4
```

Will return the total duration in seconds. (video+audio) = 124.693091

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 movie.mp4
```

Will return only video duration in seconds `stream=duration` = 123.256467

```
ffprobe -v error -sexagesimal -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 movie.mp4
```

Will return only video duration using the `-sexagesimal` format. = 0:02:03.256467

Comment: can I get duration to suite `mkvmerge` I want it cut until the end of the video, and there is no option on it to know what it ends in time, in this form at `HH:MM:SS`

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have access to `ffprobe`, you could use `mediainfo`.

```
# Outputs a decimal number in seconds
mediainfo some_video --Output=JSON | jq '.media.track[0].Duration' | tr -d '"'`
```

Comment: Eliminate the need for `jq` and `tr`: `mediainfo --Output="General;%Duration/String%" input`

Comment: Neat! I'm going to leave my answer unedited for now because the output of your command is of the form `X s YYY ms` versus `X.YYY`. Easy enough to adjust with `| sed -e 's/ s /./' -e 's/ ms//'` if you want to go that route and do not have access to `jq`.

Comment: That can be changed with `mediainfo --Output="General;%Duration/String3%" input` to output `00:01:48.501` instead of `1 min 48 s`.