# Find all video files by duration

Tags: linux, script, shell-script, find

I want to move all video files with a certain duration to some directory. 
In [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/776168/661137) I found a way to probe the duration of a video file:

```
ffprobe -i some_video -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

I wanted to do something like this with it:

```
find . -test <test for duration> -exec mv {} /path/to/target ';'
```

However, it seems that `find` does not support arbitrary scripts for the test (there is no `-test` switch). Did I miss something? Is this simply not possible with `find`? Am I better off just writing a python script?

Comment: which tool / os do you use?

Comment: linux and a terminal

Comment: `find` in Linux *does* support arbitrary scripts for tests. See [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1221882/432690).

Comment: When you need complex shell processing for files discovered by a `find` command, it is usually easier to use the construct `find ... | while read -r f; do ... ; done`. This allows you to use all normal scripting on the current file `"$f"` , such as `find ... | while read -r f; do DurationTest "$f" && mv "$f" "/path/to/target"/; done`. Note that this construct handles most file names, except when there are leading or trailing blanks or embedded new-lines, though leading and trailing blanks are included in "$REPLY" if you use `read -r` without a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-exec` as your `-test`. 
Write a script that takes one filename argument
and exits 0 if the file meets your condition and non-zero otherwise. 
I don’t have the FF software (e.g., `ffprobe`) software on my system,
so I can’t check this, but something like

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if dur=$(ffprobe -i "$1" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0")
then
        [ "$dur" -ge 900 ]
        exit
else
        exit
fi
```

would check for a video having duration ≥ 15 minutes,
assuming `ffprobe` outputs an integer number of seconds. 
(If it reports mm:ss or ss.ddd, I leave the trivial modifications to you,
but see my example below for inspiration.) 
Explanation: the `if` fails if `ffprobe` fails;
in that case, we drop to the lower `exit`
and exit with the error status from `ffprobe`. 
If `ffprobe` succeeds, we test its output (`"$dur"`)
and then exit with the result of that test. 
This could also be written

```sh
[ "$dur" -ge 900 ]  &&  exit 0  ||  exit 1
```

In fact, the *entire* script can really be reduced to

```sh
dur=$(ffprobe -i "$1" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0")  \
                            &&  [ "$dur" -ge 900 ]
```

So call your script something like `check_dur`; then you can do

```sh
find . -exec ./check_dur {} ';'-exec mv {} /path/to/target ';'
```

This works because, as I said, `-exec` functions as a test,
and things after a `-exec` will be processed
only if the first `-exec` succeeded (exited with status 0).

As I said,
I don’t have the FF software (e.g., `ffprobe`) software on my system,
so I tested with this script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if mod=$(stat -c%y "$1")
then
        mod=${mod#*-}
        mod=${mod%%-*}
        mod=${mod#0}
        [ $(( mod%2 )) = 0 ]
        exit
else
        exit
fi
```

which tests whether the modification date of a file or directory
is in an even-numbered month. 
Note: on my (en_US) system, `stat -c%y filename`
outputs the modification date
in the format `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.ddddddddd -(TZ)`. 
So the above code

1. strips off the year (from the left),
2. strips off everything after the month, and
3. strips off a leading `0`, if any
   (because `$((…))` interprets a leading zero
   as an indicator that a number is octal,
   and so it reports an error for `08` and `09`).

---

A couple of other notes:

1. For `mv`, the command can be improved a little by changing it to

   ```sh
    find . -exec ./check_dur {} ';' -exec mv -t /path/to/target {} +
   ```

which will execute `mv` once with many files. 
You *cannot* do this with the first `-exec`,
because `-exec ... +` cannot be used as a test. 
2. If you don’t want to write a separate script,
you can use `sh -c` and inline the script; e.g.,

```sh
    find . -exec sh -c 'dur=$(ffprobe -i "$1" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0") && [ "$dur" -ge 900 ]' sh {} ';'-exec mv -t /path/to/target {} +
```

This creates a one-line mini-script (the string after the `sh -c`)
and passes the filename (`{}`) to it as an argument. 
Some versions of `find`
will let you incorporate the `{}` into the mini-script,
but this is a bad idea:

- It doesn’t work for all versions of `find`, and
- even when it works, in general,
  it will fail (and maybe even fail catastrophically) for some filenames.